# Wordpress "Media Library" not loading. Some conflict code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently I have created a wordpress theme starting by 0. I have detected that when I include the following code at the functions.php file: `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/database.php';` to link it to a created database for my theme, the media libray doesn´t load properly.

I have other code lines referringo to a "includes" folder.

When I comment this line at the file functions.php "//", it seems that the media library loads again. It should be conflict somewhere but I dont know where. Could someone give me some advice, or let me know where to look.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you check the `error_log` and paste any warnings/notices etc?

Comment: The weird thing is that the debug.log doesn´t fill nothing. It has to be becouse this lines in the functions.php.

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/database.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/reservas.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/opciones.php';

Comment: do a `phpinfo();` and look for `error_log`. That's the real PHP error log, I assume debug.log is a Wordpress thing.

Answer (score 0):

Youc can try

```
setenforce disabled
```